# Automapper 5 do not map collections collections defined with read only properties

Tags: automapper-5

When I upgraded to Automapper 5.1.1, mapping of collections that are defined with readonly properties stopped to work (this works perfectly fine using Automapper 4.2.1)

Here is a sample code that you can try using both versions of Automapper to verify the behavior change. With automapper 5.1.1 result.MyList has zero elements.

```
class TestAutomapper
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Test, TestDto>();                
        });
        var test = new Test();
        test.MyList.Add(1);

        var result= Mapper.Map<TestDto>(test);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public List<int> MyList { get; } = new List<int>();
}

public class TestDto
{
    public List<int> MyList { get; } = new List<int>();
}
```

**How can I get the map to work correctly using Automapper 5.1.1?**

Answer (score 2):

With the *version 4.2.1*, it wasn't working for us. It's weird that it was working for you in *4.2.1*.

To make it worked with *AutoMapper 4.2.1* we had to explicitly to tell how to map the original collection to the destination one.

```
CreateMap.Map<TestDto, Test>()
      .ForMember(x => x.MyList, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.MyList));
```

Comment: Yes, properties without setters are ignored by default, that's why you need the MapFrom. But you also need UseDestinationValue (which used to be true, but no longer). [Existing destination](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/859612d672a45c62f3cce5c8b236be796497c916/src/UnitTests/CollectionMapping.cs#L26) and [new destination](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/859612d672a45c62f3cce5c8b236be796497c916/src/UnitTests/CollectionMapping.cs#L55).